# Starting with module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, module-pattern

I'm trying to start using moddule pattern in my JS code from the beginning but I have problems to understand how to perform this kind of code design.

This is a simple event:

```
$('#docTable').on('dblclick', 'tbody tr.line', function (event) {
    $('#modal1').modal({ keyboard: false, backdrop: "static", dismiss: "modal" });
    $('#modal1').modal('show');
```

});

I've created a couple of JS files. View.js:

```
var task = window.task || {};
task.View = (function () {

function View(rootElement) {
    var dom = {
        table: $('#docTable'),
        },
        callbacks = {
            onsubmit: undefined
        };

    return {

    };
}

return View;
}());
```

and Controller.js:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {

var View = task.View(document);    

});
```

but I have no idea how to continue and catch the dblclick event.

Could anybody please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 'class' View and add event binding to its prototype. After that you can use it on multiple tables. If you want to have access to element in table you can add classes to them and find them in `defineDOM` method:

### View.js

```
var task = window.task || {};
task.View = function (table) {
    this.$table = $(table);
    this.init();
};

task.View.prototype ={
    init: function () {
        this.defineDOM();
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    defineDOM: function() {
        // Search for DOM elements in context of table element
        this.$button = $('.docButton', this.$table);
        this.$links = $('.docLinks', this.$table);
    },

    bindEvents: function () {
        this.$table.on('dblclick', 'tbody tr.line', this.onDblClick.bind(this))
    },

    onDblClick: function () {
        $('#modal1').modal({ keyboard: false, backdrop: "static", dismiss: "modal" });
        $('#modal1').modal('show');
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    new task.View('#docTable');
});
```